# adding to a query set from another queryset django

Tags: python, django

I have a query set that looks like this.

```
<QuerySet [<Room: localhost>, <Room: chat>]>
```

which is inside `room`

```
<QuerySet [<RoomShare: Shared room u'208349023840928', for company 2>]>
```

which is stored inside `roomshare`

If I print the second query to get the name of the room i just use.

```
for x in roomshare:
            print(x.room.room_name)
which gives me `Room Fun`
```

I would like to add this `Room_Fun` to the first query set.

And it should look like this

```
<QuerySet [<Room: localhost>, <Room: chat>, <Room: Room_Fun]>
```

I tried different method's but couldn't achieve the result I want.
Also the second query set can have more than 1 roomShare, so I might have to use a forloop to add multiple of times to the first query set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use itertools `chain` method to append querysets, lists etc.
Let's say, you already have two querysets `rooms` and `roomshares`.

`from itertools import chain
rooms_from_roomshares = [x.room for x in roomshares]
all_rooms = list(chain(rooms, rooms_from_roomshares))`

Comment: if I want to have lets say not just the roomshares name but also id, then can it be [x for x in roomshares]?

Comment: [x.id for x in roomshares] will give you list of roomshares ids. [x.room.id for x in roomshares] will give you list of room ids in roomshares.

Comment: But with your code only the room name gets attached to all_rooms, the query set I have in roomshares has the name of the roomshare and also the id of the roomshare, so I was wondering is it possible to attach the ID as well, not just the name

Comment: Can you post your models.py showing the relation between room and roomshare?

Comment: In my code, rooms_from_roomshares list saves the room objects and not room names. So in all_rooms, its basically chaining room objects from 'rooms' queryset and rooms objects from 'rooms_from_roomshares' list.

Comment: the models.py does not have relation since its coming from two different query set hence its hard to answer this questions.

All I want to know is that, all this names in rooms and roomshare has a uuid which needs to be present, and when you do the for x in roomshares, does the uuid go away or stays for room_fun?

Comment: I am not getting what you are trying to say. [x for x in roomshares] will give you roomshares objects list.  [x.room for x in roomshares] will give you room objects list.  [x.room.uuid for x in roomshares] will give you room uuids   list.